# A cupboard with two shelves, finding the minimal coordinates to fit a fixed volume inside

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

> A cupboard with two shelves with height $y$, width $x$ and depth $d$ (in cm units).
>
> 1. Find for the required wood area to build the cupboard.
>
>    Find the cupboard coordinates in the least expensive way, such that the volume size inside the cupboard is $100\,\text{cm}^3$. How much would it cost if the price of the wood is $\$100$ per $100\,\text{cm}^3$?

[image]

My approach is the following:
\begin{align*}
&\text{Cupboard area:} &&f(x, y, d)=3xy+2yd+xd\\
&\text{Volume: } &&xyd=100.
\end{align*}
*Now get $d$ with respect to $x$ and $y$:*
$$d=\frac{100}{xy},\quad f(x,y)=3xy+\frac{200}{x}+\frac{100}{y}.$$
*Compute the partial derivatives and set them to zero:*
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=3y-\frac{200}{x^2}=0 \Longrightarrow y=\frac{200}{3x^2},\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=3x-\dfrac{100}{y^2}=0 \Longrightarrow x=\frac{100}{3y^2},\\
x= \frac{2\sqrt[3]{450}}{3},\quad y=\sqrt[3]{\frac{50}{3}},\quad d=\frac{150\sqrt[3]{3}}{\sqrt[3]{22500}}.$$

I am not sure about the answers nor the approach, I have seen almost similar problems but still not sure.

If anyone could confirm my approach or give some hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems good to me, except for a few minor details:

- Seems to be a typo for y in the final answer; should be cube root, not square root. I believe the answer is $x = \sqrt[3]{\frac{400}{3}}$, $y = \sqrt[3]{\frac{50}{3}}$.
- Shouldn't it be $f(x, y, d) = 3xd + 2yd + xy$?
- You can use Lagrange multipliers, and the calculations may be a little simpler, but your method is perfectly fine.
- Technically you need to check for x = 0 or y = 0 since you assumed they are not 0 when you divided by them. But by common sense we know that the answer will not have 0 in it.

**UPDATE**:

Using Lagrange multipliers, let $f(x, y, d) = 3xd + 2yd + xy$, $g(x, y, d) = xyd - 100$. Then we must have $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ and $g(x, y, d) = 0$. The former is
$$\begin{bmatrix}
3d + y \\
2d + x \\
3x + 2y
\end{bmatrix}
= \lambda \begin{bmatrix}
yd \\
xd \\
xy \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Actually, this system of equations seems pretty hard to solve, so perhaps your method was better after all.

Comment: True, I made a miscalculation for the x, by f(x,y)=3xd+2yd+xy, you meant f(x,y,d)? if so, I double checked it, didn't see the mistake.

Comment: If you don't mind, give me your approach using the Lagrange multipliers (just a starter, without calculations).

Comment: If shelves are horizontal, and x is the length and d is the depth (distance from you to wall across the cupboard), then there should be three plates of area xd, right?

Comment: Also, I didn't say your x is incorrect. It's just a different form of my expression of cube root of 400/3.

Comment: By d, I mean the z-axis, If that's the confusion all about

Comment: Oh, I see, yes I made a typo in y

Comment: I guess, it just seemed that y, height, should refer to how tall the cupboard is vertically.

Comment: I asked my professor for a clarification about the 'd', so you were right about f(x,y,d)=3xd+2yd+xy